# Flask - Toggle button with dynamic label

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am new to Flask and want to create a On/Off toggle button on my website. I was wondering if and how this is possible also including a dynamic label. The following picture shows what I have in mind:

[image]

I was thinking about using a `wtfforms` `SubmitField` but I don't quite know how to implement this dynamic behavior between my routes.py file and my html template. I was thinking something like this:

forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField

class PowerSwitchForm(FlaskForm):
    power_switch = SubmitField("ON")
```

routes.py:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from app import app
from app.forms import PowerSwitchForm

@app.route('/power', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def power():
  power_switch = PowerSwitchForm()
  if power_switch.power_switch.label.text == "ON" and power_switch.validate():
    flash("Power has been turned ON")
    power_switch.power_switch.label.text = "OFF"
    return redirect(url_for('power')
  elif power_switch.power_switch.label.text == "OFF" and power_switch.validate():
    flash("Power has been turned OFF")
    power_switch.power_switch.label.text = "ON"
    return redirect(url_for('power')
  return render_template('power.html', form0=power_switch)
```

power.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Power switch</h2>
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
  {{ form0.hidden_tag() }}
  {{ form0.power_switch() }}
</form>    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have `<form action="/power/" method="post" novalidate>`?

Comment: It's the same. When the `action` is set to an empty string the form is submitted to the URL that is currently in the address bar, which is the URL that rendered the form on the page.

Comment: Do you want to reload the page each time the switch is clicked?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what the best practice would be. I guess this isn't necessary. The above code is just my naive starting point. My main problem is the dynamic label change of the button.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `jquery` to handle the desired operation when the toggle button is clicked. Also, if there is a backend process that should be performed when the button is toggled, `ajax` can be used. This answer demonstrates both. [`bootstrap-toggle`](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) is a library that enables simple implementation of a toggle. To use, copy the `header` tag values below:

#### Simple toggle that displays "toggled" or "untoggled":

```
<html>
  <body>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <input type="checkbox" class='toggle' checked data-toggle="toggle">
    <div class='status'>Toggled</div>
  </body>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.toggle').click(function() {
      var current_status = $('.status').text();
      if (current_status === 'Untoggled'){
         $('.status').html('Toggled');
      }
      else{
        $('.status').html('Untoggled');
      }

    });
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

[image]

#### Toggle that triggers backend script for both "toggled" or "untoggled":

In the template, slightly change the `script`:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
   var current_status = $('.status').text();
   $.ajax({
    url: "/get_toggled_status",
    type: "get",
     data: {status: current_status},
     success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
     },
     error: function(xhr) {
      //Do Something to handle error
     }
   });
  });
});
</script>
```

Then, in your app, create a route `/get_toggled_status`:

```
@app.route('/get_toggled_status') 
def toggled_status():
  current_status = flask.request.args.get('status')
  return 'Toggled' if current_status == 'Untoggled' else 'Untoggled'
```

This example does the same thing as the pure `html`/`jquery` solution, however, it does demonstrate how the backend can be communicated with when using the toggle.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to Flask. And here is the pure python code with flask that I've tried.
Looks it work.

in templates/demo.html :

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block content %}
<div class="page-header">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

in demo.py :

```
from flask              import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for                          
from flask_bootstrap    import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf          import FlaskForm
from wtforms            import SubmitField

class PowerState(FlaskForm) :
    state = SubmitField('OFF')

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'YOUR SECRET KEY'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home() :
    form = PowerState()

    if form.validate_on_submit() :
        if form.state.label.text == 'OFF' :
            PowerState.state = SubmitField('ON')
        elif form.state.label.text == 'ON' :
            PowerState.state = SubmitField('OFF')

        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('demo.html', form=form)
```

then run :
flask run

Regards, Alex.Wu