# Flask Toggle Button

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I want to add a toggle button to my page and saw this previous question: [Flask - Toggle button with dynamic label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057966/flask-toggle-button-with-dynamic-label). I did some testing with it and it worked as expected and I was so excited to implement! Then I moved the code over to my actual .html file and for some reason it isn't working. I have been working in Flask for about a week now and it's very rewarding but I am still quite new so I'm not sure what is going on.

HTML:

```
{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h2>{{ mType }}</h2>
    {% if rType == "Test"%}
        <h3>Test</h3>
    {% endif %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">{% include "safetychanges.html" %}</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="load3" class="load3">
          <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('tasks') }}">
            <input type="submit" value="Start/Stop Recording" name="rec" />
            </form>
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end">


            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('tasks') }}">
            </form>
            <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" height="100%", width="100%">


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

<html>
  <body>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <input type="checkbox" class='toggle' checked data-toggle="toggle">
    <div class='status'>Toggled</div>
  </body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
   var current_status = $('.status').text();
   console.log("here");
   $.ajax({
    url: "/Planning/get_toggled_status",
    type: "get",
     data: {status: current_status},
     success: function(response) {
      $(".status").html(response);
     },
     error: function(xhr) {
      //Do Something to handle error
     }
   });
  });
});
</script>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('/Planning/get_toggled_status')
def toggled_status():
  current_status = request.args.get('status')
  print("hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")
  print(current_status)
  return 'Toggled' if current_status == 'Untoggled' else 'Untoggled'
```

From my best estimates while testing, it's like the script isn't being triggered while in my html code opposed to when I was testing it in an empty html code file. Any ideas?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @unmitigated no errors in the console unfortunately